# Preventing JqueryMobile SimpleDialog Cache

Tags: jquery-mobile

Headers:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" /> 

    <style>
        /* App custom styles */
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js">
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.js"></script><script>$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = false;
$('.ui-page').live('pagehide',function(){ $(this).remove(); });</script>
```

When I use:

```
            $(document).delegate('#btnComment', 'click', function() {
                $(this).simpledialog({
                    'mode':'blank',
                    'prompt':false,
                    'forceInput':true,
                    'cleanOnClose' : true, //!important..doesnt work
                    'useModal':true,
                    'fullHTML': ''                  })
            });
```

What ever I put in fullHTML, is cached.

Whe n the user changes page, and I REOPEN the dialog, the contents is not updated, it still always shows the old contents from the previous page.

I have tried countless suggestions that are already available on the internet. There are no options left, or I am doing something wrong. I would really appreachiate some advise on how to either properly disable cache (i also use php headers to say no cache) or how to properly dispose of this dialog!!!!!!!!!!!! reinitializing it should surely render a new one no?? cleanOnClose .. even clicking cancel does not resolve the problem and thats using close rel

```
                        +'<table style="width:100%"><tr><td style="width:50%"><a id="btnSubmitComment" rel="save" data-role="button" href="javascript:submitCommentForm();" id="simpleclose">Save</a></td><td style="width:50%">'
                        +'<a rel="close" data-role="button" href="#" id="simpleclose">Cancel</a></td></tr></table>'
```

also this doesnt help

```
;$(this).simpledialog('refresh');
```

Comment: Chris - this is probably about a month too late, but I did push a new version of this (called, oddly enough, SimpleDialog2) - it fixes a lot of the huge issues with "fullHTML"

Answer (score 0):

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
window.location = uri;

<a data-ajax="false" href="javascript:gotouri('
```